# no such table: users_user

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I need to create POST method Registration Form i have this code (i am using django rest_framework):
Users.models

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = 'username'

class MyUserManager(CreateAPIView):
    def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.data.get('username')
        email = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        user = model(username=username, email=normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        return user
```

users.serializers:

```
class MyUserManagerSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']
```

and models.views.py:

```
class UserManagerAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyUserManagerSerializers
    def UserRegistration(request):
        user = UserManager.post(request)
        serializers = MyUserManagerSerializers(user)
        serializers.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializers.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register', UserManagerAPIView.as_view()),
```

and installed_apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ['users.apps.UsersConfig']
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

when i am send POST method to localhost:8000/register i always get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such table: users_user) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 242, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 24, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 205, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 939, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py", line 198, in execute
    return self._record(self.cursor.execute, sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py", line 133, in _record
    return method(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /register
Exception Value: no such table: users_user
```

I am new in django, but i checked docs, check stack overflow, checked othe forums and can't to find how to fix this error, may be it is my bad. Because i think my register form is so bad, but how can i fix this? I did all migrations, and always i see "succesfully!".

Comment: Did you *make* migrations (`manage.py makemigrations`)? Is `users` registered for the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your User model:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
# You have to override the usermanager!

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=email, **extra_fields) # Here I set the email as the username!
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField('Email', unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' # Again!
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['first_name', 'last_name', ] # Here you can add the fields that you want or the fields that you maybe create!

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    objects = UserManager()
```

In your admin.py:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin, messages
from django.contrib.admin.options import IS_POPUP_VAR
from django.contrib.admin.utils import unquote
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
    AdminPasswordChangeForm, 
)
from .models import CustomUser  # Here! You have to import your User not the default user!
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm # Import the forms tha you create and set bellow!
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.db import router, transaction
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.urls import path, reverse
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.views.decorators.debug import sensitive_post_parameters

csrf_protect_m = method_decorator(csrf_protect)
sensitive_post_parameters_m = method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters())


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_form_template = 'admin/auth/user/add_form.html'
    change_user_password_template = None
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {
            'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions'),
        }),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    change_password_form = AdminPasswordChangeForm
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups')
    search_fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    ordering = ('username',)
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return self.add_fieldsets
        return super().get_fieldsets(request, obj)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Use special form during user creation
        """
        defaults = {}
        if obj is None:
            defaults['form'] = self.add_form
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **defaults)

    def get_urls(self):
        return [
            path(
                '<id>/password/',
                self.admin_site.admin_view(self.user_change_password),
                name='auth_user_password_change',
            ),
        ] + super().get_urls()

    def lookup_allowed(self, lookup, value):
        # Don't allow lookups involving passwords.
        return not lookup.startswith('password') and super().lookup_allowed(lookup, value)

    @sensitive_post_parameters_m
    @csrf_protect_m
    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        with transaction.atomic(using=router.db_for_write(self.model)):
            return self._add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

    def _add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        # It's an error for a user to have add permission but NOT change
        # permission for users. If we allowed such users to add users, they
        # could create superusers, which would mean they would essentially have
        # the permission to change users. To avoid the problem entirely, we
        # disallow users from adding users if they don't have change
        # permission.
        if not self.has_change_permission(request):
            if self.has_add_permission(request) and settings.DEBUG:
                # Raise Http404 in debug mode so that the user gets a helpful
                # error message.
                raise Http404(
                    'Your user does not have the "Change user" permission. In '
                    'order to add users, Django requires that your user '
                    'account have both the "Add user" and "Change user" '
                    'permissions set.')
            raise PermissionDenied
        if extra_context is None:
            extra_context = {}
        username_field = self.model._meta.get_field(self.model.USERNAME_FIELD)
        defaults = {
            'auto_populated_fields': (),
            'username_help_text': username_field.help_text,
        }
        extra_context.update(defaults)
        return super().add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

    @sensitive_post_parameters_m
    def user_change_password(self, request, id, form_url=''):
        user = self.get_object(request, unquote(id))
        if not self.has_change_permission(request, user):
            raise PermissionDenied
        if user is None:
            raise Http404(_('%(name)s object with primary key %(key)r does not exist.') % {
                'name': self.model._meta.verbose_name,
                'key': escape(id),
            })
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = self.change_password_form(user, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                change_message = self.construct_change_message(request, form, None)
                self.log_change(request, user, change_message)
                msg = gettext('Password changed successfully.')
                messages.success(request, msg)
                update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(
                    reverse(
                        '%s:%s_%s_change' % (
                            self.admin_site.name,
                            user._meta.app_label,
                            user._meta.model_name,
                        ),
                        args=(user.pk,),
                    )
                )
        else:
            form = self.change_password_form(user)

        fieldsets = [(None, {'fields': list(form.base_fields)})]
        adminForm = admin.helpers.AdminForm(form, fieldsets, {})

        context = {
            'title': _('Change password: %s') % escape(user.get_username()),
            'adminForm': adminForm,
            'form_url': form_url,
            'form': form,
            'is_popup': (IS_POPUP_VAR in request.POST or
                         IS_POPUP_VAR in request.GET),
            'add': True,
            'change': False,
            'has_delete_permission': False,
            'has_change_permission': True,
            'has_absolute_url': False,
            'opts': self.model._meta,
            'original': user,
            'save_as': False,
            'show_save': True,
            **self.admin_site.each_context(request),
        }

        request.current_app = self.admin_site.name

        return TemplateResponse(
            request,
            self.change_user_password_template or
            'admin/auth/user/change_password.html',
            context,
        )

    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
        """
        Determine the HttpResponse for the add_view stage. It mostly defers to
        its superclass implementation but is customized because the User model
        has a slightly different workflow.
        """
        # We should allow further modification of the user just added i.e. the
        # 'Save' button should behave like the 'Save and continue editing'
        # button except in two scenarios:
        # * The user has pressed the 'Save and add another' button
        # * We are adding a user in a popup
        if '_addanother' not in request.POST and IS_POPUP_VAR not in request.POST:
            request.POST = request.POST.copy()
            request.POST['_continue'] = 1
        return super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)
```

Create a forms.py and add:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', )
        labels = {'username': 'Username/Email'}

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', )
```

That's it!

Comment: I need to do Email as Username, how can i do this with my method? or i need to rewrite all code?

Comment: You need to rewrite your code! I'll update my answer to you be able to have the email as your username!

Comment: Done! Take a look! Maybe help you!

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, i'll check this and sort out. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

run command
`python manage.py makemigrations users`